# How to modify existing JavaScript on web parts page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, 2016, web-part-page

I'm getting a syntax error in the console on a web parts page.  I can clearly see the typo, but I can't figure out how to modify the page's source code because it will only allow me to modify the page in-browser.

How can I modify the source code -- or at least the JavaScript -- on any given web parts page?

**This is the typo:** (It's using `&quot` instead of actual quotes (`"`))

```
if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == &quot;function&quot;) 

    {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}// ]]>
```